# How do I pipe a model query into the Django Shell via a Bash Script?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I'm writing a startup.sh script to be ran when a docker container is created.

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py makemigrations accounts
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py check_permissions    
python manage.py cities --import=country --force

*python manage.py shell | from cities.models import * Country.objects.all().exclude(name='United States").delete()*

python manage.py cities --import=cities
python manage.py cities --import=postal_code
```

I am guessing the line in question is incorrect, what would be the correct way to do this in a bash script?

Comment: Also open to any suggestions of a better way to do this

Comment: In terms of trying to get a better feel for how pipelines work in bash -- `foo | bar` connects the stdout of `foo` to the stdin of `bar`. Thus, the command you proposed sends the output of `python manage.py shell` to the input of a command named `from`, with its second argument `cities.models`, &c.

Comment: You could perhaps do this the other way: `printf '%s\n' 'from cities.models import *' 'Country.objects.all().exclude(name="United States").delete()' | python manage.py shell` -- that way you're sending the *output* of a `printf` command that generates your script as the *input* to the `manage.py shell` command.

Answer (score 3):

Use a heredoc:

```
python manage.py shell <<'EOF'
from cities.models import *
Country.objects.all().exclude(name='United States').delete()
EOF
```

Comment: I am going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not such a good idea to include django code in a shell script file. It's better to either make a python file and put those code in it and do:

```
python manage.py shell < script.py
```

Or better, write a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/). In this way you could track your code in the same project/repo and people got less confused when they see this.

Comment: Thumbs-up for the management command suggestion. I actually think I prefer either the management-command approach or the heredoc approach to `python manage.py shell <script.py` -- in the latter case, you have a `script.py` that won't run unless invoked in a very specific way, whereas either the heredoc or the management command are provided in a context that makes their invocation obvious.